# How to give directory as source in Mirth Connect 2.2.1?

Tags: javascript, mirth

I am using the Mirth Connect version is 2.2.1. I am creating a channel for that in source I am giving input i.e., source folder is a directory, it contains multiple folders, inside folders files are there. If files are placed in parent directory the source can able to read, but if placed inside sub directories it cannot able to find.

Please suggest some fruitful solution for reading all sub-directories.

Note: In latest mirth connect i.e., 3.0, there is a option for including the sub directories, but in older version i.e., 2.2.1 the option is available, I need a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/forums/showthread.php?t=7880, check the link, directory is reading example.